# Content div with overflow-y not stopping at the bottom of the picture

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow

The content is scrolling right up to the top of the div `#photos` without it stopping at the bottom of the picture and text `D`

```css
#mainContent {
  padding: 2px 0;
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 45%;
  background-color: #CCC;
}
#photos {
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 35%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainContent">
  <div id="photos">
    <div class="left imgbox">
      <img src="images/a.jpg" alt="A" />
    </div>
    <div class="details">A</div>
    <div class="left imgbox">
      <img src="images/b.JPG" alt="B" />
    </div>
    <div class="details">B</div>
    <div class="left imgbox">
      <img src="images/c.jpg" alt="C" />
    </div>
    <div class="details">C</div>
    <div class="left imgbox">
      <img src="images/d.jpg" alt="D" />
    </div>
    <div class="details">D</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you fiddle it?

Comment: What do you want it to look like?

Comment: hahaha thats because of padding

Comment: @Gacci, I have tried that, but it doesn't display anything

Comment: @felixsturm, you're correct, I don't know why I changed the css styling on this, hahaha

Comment: Ehm, is the question answered now? The comments are not too clear.

Comment: @MrLister yes, thanks